# Ecalp function on R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, error-message

I am doing some model validation and calibration of training data fit to use with glm and gam models, and I am having a problem with the ecalp function.

Does anyone had this problem before? Any solution

```
Model_calibration_table_TRAIN<-data.frame()
DATA2<-data.frame(TRAIN$Latitude, TRAIN$SPECIES, TRAIN$GLM_pred, TRAIN$GAM_pred)
Model_calibration_table_bnd<-data.frame("Model"=c("GLM", "GAM"))
for (m in 3:4){
w<-ecalp(DATA2[,m], DATA2[,2])
w<-as.data.frame(w)
w$bin<-c(0.05,0.15,0.25,0.35,0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75,0.85,0.95)
    caltest<-lm(w~bin, data=w, subset=w>-1)
    ctest<-cor(DATA2[,m], DATA2[,2])
    Model_calibration_table_train$COR[m-2]<-ctest
Model_calibration_table_train$calibration[m-2]<-caltest$coefficients[2]
Model_calibration_table_train$bias[m-2]<-caltest$coefficients[1]
}
```

> Error: can't find the function "ecalp"